# "Like" button - wrong image is used

Tags: image, facebook-like

I have set Open Graph tags and like button on my site. Everything is ok but "image" that used for posting message is wrong. URL Linter shows right image but when I click "Like" I see wrong image. Why?
URL: http://mandarish.ru
p.s. Also "type" is shown wrong on "URL Linter".

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved!
I think because I've added `<link rel="image_src" href="...">` tag.